# AS3 send flashvar to self on navigateToURL

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, var

This is how i'm handling html flash vars:

```
var flashVars:Object = new Object();
    flashVars = this.loaderInfo.parameters;

for (var item:String in flashVars)
{
    switch (item)
    {           
        case "phoneNumber" :
            phoneNum = String(flashVars[item]);
            break;          

    }

}
```

A little verbose for only one var, but i like to be flexible to change later on in the project..

anyways, it was more efficient to compose a quick reset function that simply reloads the swf than it would be to compose a matrix of properties for objects that i'm manipulating within the swf; thus, I'm using the following code:

```
function reset(){

    var url = stage.loaderInfo.url;
    var request = new URLRequest(url);  
    navigateToURL(request,"_level0");
}
```

What I need to do is pass the flashvars from the flashVars object to the request var and i think having a fever is making me over think this... anyone done this before?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just pass the flashvars data object to the `data` property of your URLRequest:

```
var url = stage.loaderInfo.url;
var request = new URLRequest(url);  

request.data = stage.loaderInfo.parameters

navigateToURL(request,"_level0");
```

Comment: I've never actually tried it, but it should work without having to parse the data.

Comment: for whomever down voted, it is of no use to anyone unless you explain your reason.